# Convert Dates in C#

Tags: .net, datetime, icalendar

Does anyone know of an easy (built in) way to convert a string like '20081231T130000' (ICalendar I think) to DateTime in C#?
Or do I need to parse the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime when = DateTime.ParseExact("20081231T130000",
    "yyyyMMddTHHmmss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Aside: it is *close* to the format used in xml, but not quite close enough - otherwise `XmlConvert` wraps this:

```
DateTime when = XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2008-12-31T13:00:00");
```

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work:

```
string dateTimeString = "20080115T115959";
string format = "yyyyMMddTHHmmss";
IFormatProvider us = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, format, us);
```

Comment: The hh should be HH to use a 24 hour clock.

Comment: Needs to be HH (0-23), not hh (0-11) - and invariant would probably do just fine since there is no culture-specific info in the string.

Comment: Thanks for catching that...  I guess that's why I'm only at 11 reputation :)

Comment: Virtual +1 for the HH comments to Jon and Marc. I've just spent an hour thinking "that worked this morning" ... :)